# Is it possible to add children to d3.hierarchy dynamically?

Tags: d3.js

Most cases use static json data to generate a tree graph or collapsible force graph by using d3.hierarchy. But the problem is what about the data is dynamic rather than static? On the other word, are there any ways or functions to add children into d3.hierarchy object which is already existing?

I have read many [examples](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288) about how to make a Collapsible Force-Directed by using D3. But most of them are using static json data.

example code structure:

```
data = JSON.parse(my_json)
const root = d3.hierarchy(data);
...
function update(){
      const nodes = flatten(root);
      const links = root.links();
}
...
```

What I need to do is if have a root node as followed:

```
var data = {name: "flare",children: []}
const root = d3.hierarchy(data);
...
```

Then I shall add child into root.children

```
var child = {name: "animate", children: []}
```

So that I do not need to recreate a hierarchy for root data, I can just create a child hierarchy object and add it into root.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. You have to create you own function to match dynamic data situation.